comma before and. What does it mean?
What does the , and part mean:

The property is not in an area where the Coal Authority has received
an application for, and is
currently considering whether to grant a licence to remove or work coal by underground methods.

does it mean:

The property is not in an area where the Coal Authority has received
an application for.

and

[The property is not in an area] currently considering whether to grant a licence
to remove or work coal by underground methods

or does the , and mean:

The property is not in an area where the Coal Authority has received
an application for.

and

[the property] is currently considering whether to grant a licence to
remove or work coal by underground methods


Suffice it to say that this sentence is poorly written, so much so that the meaning is unclear. I can guess at a meaning, but someone else guessed differently. I would put it behind me and not worry about making sense of incoherent writing.

I don't think the comma is syntactically necessary, but if it is present, there should be anther one after grant, since the entirety of and is currently considering whether to grant is an optional  "parenthetical" element (that can be removed in its entirety, and still leave a valid utterance). It's not very well written, but that's "legalese" for you.

Wow, this is a convoluted sentence. My best guess is that it means:

This property is not in an area for which the Coal Authority has received and is currently considering an application for a licence to remove or work coal by underground methods.

In other words, there's no open application for a licence to work coal in the area.

The writer faced two difficulties that led them to write their version:

Two verbs ("received" and "is currently considering") that share a single object ("an application").

Some writers avoid this sort of coordination, because delaying the object until after the second verb risks making the first verb sound ungrammatical or intransitive. The writer avoided the coordination periphrastically with "whether to grant", but this only complicates the syntax.
In my rewrite, I opted for a simple coordination. But it's worth noting that eliminating the first verb would yield functionally the same meaning anyway.

Ambiguous relationship of "application", "licence", and "area".

One might say an application/licence for or concerning the area, an application/licence to work coal in the area, or an application/licence to remove coal from the area. Or one might say an application for a licence to work coal in the area... and so forth. The writer unfortunately opted for "an area where they have received an application for (a licence)", which is quite difficult to parse because it sounds like a failed "for which" structure.
In my rewrite, I used "for which", which creates the relationship "a licence for an area". This subsumes the relationships "a licence to remove coal from an area or work coal in an area", which seem too cumbersome to mention individually.

Actually, the original is so malformed that I took a different meaning: The Coal Authority has not received an application for the area that the property is in, AND the Coal Authority is currently considering whether to grant a license [i.e. overlook the lack of application]. If this is the meaning, I don't think there's any way to pass the original version as gramatically valid.

@AndyBonner Hmm, I find that reading both hard to extract from the sentence — you might contend that it accounts for the comma, but I think the comma is just the writer's allergy to coordinated verbs sharing an object — and somewhat ad hoc logically. Of course, we'd need context to know whether the CA grants licences for fun to potential coalworkers (?) without an application, but I suspect that the underlying structure is simply "an application for a licence". In other words, the least effort to salvage the sentence as written would have been to put a comma after "grant".

I agree with Luke here. The negating not of preceding not in an area... clearly extends to both the following clauses (not received..., and not currently considering...).

Legal document.
OP has given a sentence from a legal document and has asked for clarification.
A Google search has revealed that it is a sample for coal mining report.

The property is not in an area where the Coal Authority has received an application for, and is currently considering whether to grant a licence to remove or work coal by underground methods.

Comma before "and" is as per comma rules. It separates the coordinating clause

Ref. East Stroudsburg University
Two Independent Clauses in a Compound Sentence with a Coordinating Conjunction. When you have two sentences that can stand on their own and are connecting it with a conjunction (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so), you must put a comma on the word before the conjunction.
https://www.esu.edu/writing-studio/guides/comma-rules

Independent clause (after correction).
the Coal Authority  is currently considering whether to grant a licence to remove  coal by underground methods.
Please keep in mind that this is a sample report, and some misleading language have been introduced so that a client should contact the law firm rather than copy it straight. The contact numbers are given in the report.(link given below)



The given sentence comes under future mining. It mentions that the coal under a property can be removed by underground method.
https://www.severntrentsearches.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ResEngland-WalesOnCoalfield.pdf
